# How to show table and total cost together?

Tags: mysql, addition

I am trying to show a list of costs and have the total at the bottom of my list:

```
mysql> select   title_name, rental_transaction, renter_lname,renter_fname, rental_cost
    -> from  rentals
    -> where rental_date between '161201' and  '161219'
    -> and  DATEDIFF(date(rental_return_date ), date(rental_date ))  > 7;
+----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| title_name                 | rental_transaction | renter_lname | renter_fname | rental_cost |
+----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| WarioWare Touched!         |                 13 | Brennan      | Kathleen     |        2.99 |
| Hot Shots Golf: Open Tee   |                 23 | Grey-Gubler  | Eva          |        3.99 |
| WarioWare Touched!         |                 29 | Smithers     | Kieran       |        2.99 |
| The Urbz: Sims in the City |                 56 | Winters      | Emily        |        4.99 |
| Lumines: Puzzle Fusion     |                 68 | Ryan         | Rebecca      |        3.99 |
| WarioWare Touched!         |                 89 | Byrne        | Ann          |        2.99 |
+----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I basically want this table, but I want to show the total cost of the rentals at the bottom of the table and am wondering if this is possible to do?

Comment: Honestly, I would do this in two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `UNION`.
But as `UNION` needs the two queries to have the same number of columns you will need to add some `null as columnName`

The query:

```
select   title_name, rental_transaction, renter_lname,renter_fname, rental_cost
from  rentals
where rental_date between '161201' and  '161219'
and  DATEDIFF(date(rental_return_date ), date(rental_date ))  > 7;
union 
select 'total_cost', null as columnName, null as columnName, null as columnName, sum(rental_cost)
from rentals
```

The result:

[image]